# Most Efficiently Iterating Large List of Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have seen some answers for similar questions but I am not sure that they were the best way to fix my problem.

I have a very large table (100,000+ rows of 20+ columns) being handled as a list of dictionaries.  I need to do a partial deduplication of this list using a comparison.  I have simplified an example of what I am doing now below.

```
table = [
    { "serial": "111", "time": 1000, "name": jon },
    { "serial": "222", "time": 0900, "name": sal },
    { "serial": "333", "time": 1100, "name": tim },
    { "serial": "444", "time": 1300, "name": ron },
    { "serial": "111", "time": 1300, "name": pam }
    ]

for row in table:
    for row2 in table:
        if row != row2:
            if row['serial'] == row2['serial']:
                if row['time'] > row2['time']:
                    action
```

This method does work (obviously simplified and just wrote "action" for that part) but the question I have is whether there is a more efficient method to get to the "row" that I want without having to double iterate the entire table.  I don't have a way to necessarily predict where in the list matching rows would be located, but they would be listed under the same "serial" in this case.

I'm relatively new to Python and efficiency is the goal here.  As of now with the amount of rows that are being iterated it is taking a long time to complete and I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this, I'm just not sure where to start.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you can't/don't want to/ go with pandas or something similar, and depending on the cardinality of the primary keys, you could build one big dictionary, having `serial` as keys, and then check `time`/take action in parallel.

Comment: In the modern world, >100k is next to nothing actually.

Comment: Thanks @khachik I considered doing a large dictionary build but I would have a duplicate issue because there are some duplicates that wouldn't have action taken.  For example, 'serial' could have multiple matches but I would only be taking action on one row that matched.  If I did go this route and possibly combined column values for a unique key, would I just do a 'for row' once through to build a large dictionary and then run through once more referencing back against the large dictionary that was built?  This would be two loops through rather than the large combination that it currently is.

Comment: You need to stop using a list of dictionaries. This is basically the worst of both worlds as far as what these data-structures are designed to do. Instead, keep a list of records (probably named-tuples) *using a dict as an index* with each key-value being a list of nametuples. Or something like that.

Comment: I agree that it seems totally inefficient but in this case I can’t control the format of the data going in.

Comment: @GiraffeMan91 I mean you append the duplicates to the value of the given serial and run dedup/actions in parallel, for each `serial -> list of dicts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the table with `serial` as the primary key and `time` as the secondary key, in reverse order (so that the latter of the duplicate items take precedence), then iterate through the sorted list and take action only on the first dict of every distinct `serial`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
table = [
    { "serial": "111", "time": "1000", "name": "jon" },
    { "serial": "222", "time": "0900", "name": "sal" },
    { "serial": "333", "time": "1100", "name": "tim" },
    { "serial": "444", "time": "1300", "name": "ron" },
    { "serial": "111", "time": "1300", "name": "pam" }
]
last_serial = ''
for d in sorted(table, key=itemgetter('serial', 'time'), reverse=True):
    if d['serial'] != last_serial:
        action(d)
    last_serial = d['serial']
```

Comment: This makes sense.  Sorting should prevent me from having to iterate the entire list.  I will look again at my actual data set and see if this method would have any problems but it seems like it should work.

Answer (score 2):

A list of dictionaries is *always* going to be fairly slow for this much data. Instead, look into whether [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is suitable for your use case - it is already optimised for this kind of work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I will look into seeing if we can get Pandas in the environment I'm working with but at the moment I don't believe that I can, unfortunately.  It does look like Pandas would solve this nearly immediately.

Comment: What's slow here is the *list*, not the dictionaries. The dictionaries are simply horribly space inefficient because they are not designed as a record type.

Comment: Just to follow up, unfortunately I cannot get Pandas but I do have access to use R which may have similar abilities that I am investigating further.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be *the* most efficient, but one thing you can do is get a list of the serial numbers, then sort them. Let's call that list `serialNumbersList`. The serial numbers that only appear once, we know that they cannot possibly be duplicates, so we remove them from `serialNumbersList`. Then, you can use that list to reduce the amount of rows to process. Again, I am sure there are better solutions, but this is a good starting point.

Comment: Ah yes thank you for this.  I didn't mention it but I am already reducing the amount of rows to only known partial duplicates in a similar way before this effort which is why I'm only dealing with the amount that I am.

Answer (score 0):

@GiraffeMan91 Just to clarify what I mean (typed directly here, do not copy-paste):

```
serials = collections.defaultdict(list) 
for d in table:
    serials[d.pop('serial')].append(d)

def process_serial(entry):
    serial, values = entry
    # remove duplicates, take action based on time
    # return serial, processed values

results = dict(
    multiprocess.Pool(10).imap(process_serial, serials.iteritems())
)
```